# get() returned more than one Ubicacion -- it returned 2!

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo rutas asociadas a ubicaciones, quiero que cuando escriba 'http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ubicacion/11/' me devuelva todas las ubicaciones con la ruta de id 11 pero si tiene dos o mas me da el error :"MultipleObjectsReturned at /rest/Ubicacion/11/

get() returned more than one Ubicacion -- it returned 2!"

Mi models es el siguiente:

```
class Ubicacion(models.Model):
 nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 lat  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 lng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='')
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 TextoParaAudio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 Ruta = models.ForeignKey(Ruta,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Mi viewsets:

```
class UbicacionViewSetById(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

 serializer_class = UbicacionSerializer

 def get_queryset(self):
     id = self.kwargs['id']

     return Ubicacion.objects.filter(Ruta=id).order_by('id')
```

mi urls:

```
router.register(r'UbicacionById',UbicacionViewSetById.get_queryset,base_name="UbicacionById")     

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^admin/Rutas/ubicacion/add/', include("Rutas.urls")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest/', include(router.urls)),


] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que quieres hacer es filtrar una lista, para esto tienes que pasarle parametros con el metodo GET:

http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ubicacion/?ruta=11

y modificar el metodo get_queryset de la clase UbicacionViewSetById

```
 def get_queryset(self):
     id = self.request.GET.get('ruta')

     return Ubicacion.objects.filter(Ruta__pk=id).order_by('id')

#te recomendaria que cambies el UbicacionById por ubicaciones, siempre en plural en minúsculas, observa que he quitada el .get_queryset
router.register(r'UbicacionById',UbicacionViewSetById,base_name="UbicacionById")
```

cuando solo se pone el viewset en el router , y llamas a 
http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/UbicacionByID     esto llama automaticamente al get_queryset si quieres filtrar añades los parametros con GET ?ruta=11

http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/UbicacionByID/12  con esto de volvera automaticamente la ubicacion con el id=12

[routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) 
buenas practicas [APIRest](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)

Comment: debería poner esto para buscar: http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ubicacion/?ruta=11 porque así me salen todas las rutas la 5, la 9.
GET /rest/Ubicacion/?ruta=11
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "nombre": "deusto",
        "Ruta": "http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ruta/11/"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "universidad",
        "Ruta": "http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ruta/11/"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "casa",
        "Ruta": "http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ruta/9/"
    },
   
]

Comment: Perdona, pero no te sigo. Es lo que he dicho no?

Comment: si, perdon era un pregunta a ver si debo hacer así con esta url http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ubicacion/?ruta=11 ? porque con esta url me salen todos!gracias

Comment: Ah vale!! Es una pregunta por eso no te había entendido. Si si, es así como lo recomienda el manual de buenas prácticas de API rest, me alegro haber ayudado. Si he solucionado tu duda no olvides poner tu pregunta cómo respondida. Un saludo.

Comment: no, no! no me hace el filtrado! me muestra todas, necesito que solo se muestre la 11!Gracias

Comment: te he modificado mi  respuesta , hechale un vistazo

Comment: perdón pero no entiendo que es v1!Gracias

Comment: esta parte de la url http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/ me la he invitado por que no recordaba la tuya a eso ni caso

Comment: Solucionado, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: me alegro :D un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando el método detail y estás devolviendo varios objetos. Al pasarle la id al final estas diciendo "dame la ubicación con id 11" y después en el viewset le estás modificando el queryset y enviando varios. La forma más simple es crearte una función con el decorador `@list_route()` y pasarle como parametro la id de ruta, hacer el filter como lo estas haciendo en `get_queryset()` y después le haces esto:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset,many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

self.get_serializer puedes traducirlo por el serializer `UbicacionSerializer` si la función la sacas de viewset

Comment: Hago esto y no me funciona:
    class UbicacionViewSetById(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = UbicacionSerializer

    @list_route()
    def get_queryset(self, id):
        queryset= Ubicacion.objects.filter(Ruta=id).order_by('id')

        serializer = self.UbicacionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

Comment: no puedes utilizar la función get_queryset porque estás machacando una función propia de viewset, cambiale de nombre y llama a la url asi: `'http://10.164.61.243:8000/rest/Ubicacion/funcion/` y como parametro le pasas el 11

Comment: pero quiero que el 11 sea variable, cada vez lo que el usuario quiera!Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes pasarlo en la URL si es a lo que te refieres. Tienes que programarle una url especifica con `/res/Ubicacion/funcion/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$` de esta forma puedes sacar la id de kwargs.

Comment: pero como debería hacer el método get_queryset de UbicacionViewSetById?

Comment: no puedes utilizar el método get_queryset, estás machacando una función heredada de viewset y por eso te está dando ese error, no puedes usar el nombre get_queryset, utiliza otro nombre

Comment: class UbicacionViewSetById(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = UbicacionSerializer

    @list_route()
    def funcion(self, id):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        queryset= Ubicacion.objects.filter(Ruta=id).order_by('id')

        serializer = self.UbicacionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
router.register(r'UbicacionById',UbicacionViewSetById.funcion, base_name="UbicacionById")
        url(r'^/rest/Ubicacion/funcion/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', include(router.urls)),
cambiando el nombre del metodo y urls me sigue sin funcionar!

Comment: Como haces la llamada? comprueba que esté entrando en esa función cuando llamas a la url con un print o algo así, comprueba los logs de la terminal a ver si puedes ver donde te está surgiendo el error

Comment: Te lo he puesto en mi respuesta, no te ha servido? Puede que haya equivocado porque lo he hecho de memoria, confírmame porfa

Comment: te parece si me conecto por teamviewer? y le hecho un vistazo rapido  no tardare mas de 10 minutos

Comment: parecia que no me entraba en el método, ya esta solucionado!Muchas gracias! Un saludo